# Skydrive as TortoiseSVN repository: Access Rights?

Tags: tortoisesvn, onedrive

I am trying to use Skydrive as a SVN repository.

I mapped z:\ network drive to https://d.docs.live.net/xxxxxxxxxx (xxx... is my CID). I can now read write on Z:

I create z:\RepoSVN and right click on it>TortoiseSVN>Create repository here. Works great. Files and folders are created Inside z:\

Then in the TortoiseSVN dialog box I click "Create Directory Structure" and get this error message: **"Can't move 'Z:\RepoSVN\db\txn-575DCE6D' to 'Z:\RepoSVN\db\txn-current': Cannot create a file when that file already exists"**

I have tried to search what was wrong in the Skydrive sharing, nothing wrong I have full acess to RepoSVN (even tried to share it as public) Nothing changes.

Any idea?

Comment: Any progress? I'm going to try this as well. I'll give you an answer if I can get it to work.

Comment: I hope you succeed, I am still interested

Comment: I tried creating a repository via the skydrive installer thing that makes your skydrive look like `c:\users\me\skydrive` or whatever. It seemed to create the repository just fine, but I tried to find the repository on my other computer via skydrive and that didn't work. I'm sure there's a good reason for it. In any event, for my purposes I think I'll just be using github.com. Sorry I couldn't help you.

Comment: Thanks for trying, good luck with GitHub